# Не проходит HTTP запрос через прокси-сервер

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь через компонент **HTTPSend** библиотеки **Synapse** отправить **GET запрос** на HTTP сервер. Ну например:

```
HTTP := THTTPSend.Create;
  try
    HTTP.ProxyHost := 'PROXYHOST';
    HTTP.ProxyPort := '8080';

    if not HTTP.HTTPMethod('GET', 'http://yandex.ru') then showmessage('error');
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(HTTP.Headers);
    Memo2.Lines.LoadFromStream(HTTP.Document);
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
```

В ответ получаю следующее:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Для выполнения запроса компоненту Forefront TMG требуется авторизация. Доступ к фильтру веб-прокси запрещен.  )
    Via: 1.1 ACCESS
    Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
    Proxy-Authenticate: Kerberos
    Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 4953
```

Причем браузеры работают через этот же прокси без авторизации.
Может нужно явно какие-то параметры в заголовке указать, пробовал скопировать точь в точь парамтры запроса и его заголовок у запроса формируемого браузером при переходе на **URL**, не помогло. Причем **HTTP/HTTPS** запросы мог программно отправлять пока не поставили **Forefront TMG**. С **idHTTP** такая же проблема.
Подскажите, кто сталкивался, в чем может быть причина такого поведения.

Comment: А браузеры с этого же хоста работают без аутентификации? Или Вы этого просто не заметили (т.е. запомнен пользователь/пароль -- и ладно). Если браузеры не аутентифицируются, то прикиньтесь браузером (поле запроса user-agent). Иначе -- авторизуйтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть проблемы понял, буду разбираться дальше вот ссылочка, которая может натолкнуть на мысли если у кого то будет такая же проблема

[NTLM-аутентификация - через что лучше и как?](http://www.delphimaster.ru/cgi-bin/forum.pl?id=1283839481&n=4)